# How to prove that $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ is a smooth function?

Tags: taylor-expansion

I learned that [some functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2002875/when-is-it-invalid-to-use-taylor-series-expansion) are not equal to its taylor series, but I have a question.

How do you mathematically prove that the function$$f(x)=\begin{cases} e^{-1/x^2} &x\ne0 \\\ 0 &x=0 \end{cases}$$is infinitely differentiable and has continuous derivatives i.e. $C^{\infty}$function?

Comment: can you first prove it is differentiable at the origin and find what the derivative is?

Comment: An outline of a method of proof is given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/59907/13130). I suspect much more detailed proofs exist here, however.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Yes, using the definition of the derivative. I just don't know how to show that it's infinitely differentiable at the origin and that the derivatives are continuous.

Comment: For the case with $1/x$ instead of $1/x^2$, which is very similar, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481480/smooth-function-which-is-not-real-analytic).

Comment: If you know how to show by the definition of the derivative that $f$ itself is differentiable at $0$, can you adapt that proof to also show that for all $n \in \Bbb Z, x^nf(x)$ is differentiable at $0$? Then, adapt it a little more to show that for any rational function $R, R(x)f(x)$ is differentiable at $0$. Once you've accomplished that, you have effectively proven what you need.